Identify 70's–80's dystopian film with armored vehicle
Note: After getting the right answer I left list below unmodified because it is still how I remember the movie. For example I mixed up the roles of the man and the woman.

As a kid I saw parts of this movie at my friend's home. And now it has been about 30 years then. Nobody, even my friend, does not recall that movie. And all web searchs redirects to wrong movies (see NOT-list below). So, here is parts I remember:
Parts that most likely happened in the movie:

A woman got imprisoned. Not in a real prison. More like some house with concrete walls. (Feels like woman got intentionally imprisoned...?)
There was a man (probably bald), in prison as well, who lit a match and then spoke two to four phrases, maybe some poem?
Man dies, probably tortured to death.
Woman released or escaped somehow.
Woman finds man's van. The van is shaped like hippie van (Volkswagen Type 2) and was armored and dark colored.
Woman lights a match (or not) and repeats those same phrases what man said earlier. The door of the van opens automatically.
Van has artificial intelligence. It might spoke too (male voice?).
Woman drives off.
Some group follows the van by satellite camera. They might be builders of that van.


NOT-list: No, movie was not any of these:

Ark II (1976-1979) — Group of apes (group of humans and one chimpanzee) driving  Lotus Esprit S1 lookalike 6-wheeler RV.
Battletruck (1982), aka Warlords of the 21st Century.
Damnation Alley (1977) — Nuke the world and travel through country.
Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone (1983)
Wheels of Fire (1985) — Some Mad Max wannabe tries to save his sister or something.


I can't remember more about this movie (for now).
Edit: In Finland movies are subtitled and I can't confirm language but it was most likely English.

Could be Terminus with Karen Allen. There's an armored truck with artificial intelligence and the villains follow it remotely. I think I remember a scene with matches.

@Moritz: Bullseye! Thanks. I Youtube'd few scenes of that movie and they did fit. Although the roles were opposite in my head and some other things wrong... Memories are probably the same but reading and translating them with brain that has changed after 30 years can result funny things (:.
Can you make an answer which I can mark as The Answer? (Or how this works...)

You're welcome, I made an answer. :)

This is Terminus (1987) with Karen Allen and Jürgen Prochnow.

In a sort of "Mad Max" futuristic adventure, an international sport has been established where a driver of a computerized truck must drive across country to an established terminus and not be stopped by other vehicles. The lead truck, called "Monster" has been created by a boy genius and is to be driven by a woman through the course. The only problem is the computer guidance system fails and she ends up in uncharted territories. There she encounters leather-clad hoods who torture her and eventually kill her. Before dying she tells a fellow prisoner about the truck and he uses it to escape.





